# How to pass vairable to get() in dicitonary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, scripting

I am simply trying to solve the following question

You are given a date. Your task is to find what the day is on that date.
Sample imput : 08 10 2018

I came up with following solution:

```
days={'0':'monday','1':'tuesday','2':'wed','3':'thurs','4':'friday','5':'sat','6':'sun'}

user_input=datetime.datetime(2018, 11 ,6)

result=user_input.weekday()
print (days.get('result'))
```

Now it prints 'None' ,I was expecting this to return keys value.

Even `print(result)` returns value of **1** and `type(result)` returns **int**.

I want to know why I am not getting the expected output.
There must be a more pythonic way to do this but my major concern is the way `get()` is behaving.

Comment: I think you mean `days.get(result)` not `days.get('result')`. The string `'result'` is not in your dictionary. Though maybe the keys in your dictionary should be ints, not strings.

Comment: try `print (days.get(result))` without the quotes.

Comment: `days.get(result)`.

Comment: Either `print(days[str(result)])` or change the dictionary keys to integers and then `print(days[result])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `days.get('result')` is trying to look up the string `'result'` in your dictionary, not the variable `result`.

Secondly `user_input.weekday()` returns an int, but the keys in your dictionary are strings, not ints.

This would have worked:

```
days = {0:'monday', 1:'tuesday', 2:'wed', 3:'thurs', 4:'friday', 5:'sat', 6:'sun'}
user_input = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 6)
result = user_input.weekday()
print(days.get(result)) # or simply print(days[result])
```

However, since the possible range of days is the numbers 0 to 6, a list would work just as well.

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
user_input = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 6)
result = user_input.weekday()
print(days[result])
```

Comment: I was not aware that I am looking for result as key itself.
I was given  this question in sys admin Interview scripting part and Idk why dictionary came in mind ,I should have used list.
Thanks for the help mate.